# Binary File being read incorrectly

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a binary file to to base 10 but when I transfer the content from the binary file to an arraylist I'm getting 48 instead of 0 and 49 instead of 1.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BaseToDecimal {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
FileNotFoundException{

  //Reads in a binary file
  FileInputStream binFile = new FileInputStream("file1.bin"); 
  BufferedInputStream bufferedFile = new BufferedInputStream(binFile, 1000);

  //Puts each element from the file into an arraylist
  ArrayList<Integer> binaryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  int current = bufferedFile.read();
  while(current != -1){
     binaryList.add(current);
     current = bufferedFile.read();
  }

  //Converts binary from arraylist to base 10
  int result = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i <= binaryList.size() - 1; i++){
     result = (result * 2) + binaryList.get(i);
  }

  //prints out original binary number, number of bytes, and base 10 conversion
  System.out.print("File content: ");
  for(int i = 0; i <= binaryList.size() - 1; i++){
     System.out.print(binaryList.get(i));
  }
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Total number of bytes read: " + (binaryList.size())+ " bytes");
  System.out.println("The equivalent number in base 10 format is " + result);
 }
}
```

The Binary file is just 1011101011111011 but when read into an arraylist i am getting 49484949494849484949494949484949

Comment: Your file is not a “binary file” in the common sense of the term.  It’s a text file.  You are reading character values, not numeric values, but you are assuming they’re numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is being read as text data (ASCII) and the integer value of the character code is being passed. You will want to create a character from the value provided and then parse it as a string to retrieve the value represented by each character.